# Sorting two dimensional vector and keep tracking of original index

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to sort a list of n dimensional points by their x and store their original index:

```
original=[(3,2,3)(1,2,1)(5,1,5)]
```

after sorting:

```
[(1,2,1)(3,2,3)(5,1,5)]
```

and the index:

```
store=[1,0,2]
```

I used `vector< vector<double>` to store the n-dimensional point:

```
a[0][0] = x, a[0][1] = y, a[0][2] = z, ...
```

I wrote a mergesort to do it, transmit the `source` calling by reference
and transmit `result` calling by reference to get the index.

I encountered a problem that, if I want to print the result, the program will shut down.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfloat>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void merge(vector< vector<double> >& source, vector< int >& result, int lmin, int lmax, int rmin, int rmax){
    int i = lmin, j = rmin;
    while(i <= lmin && j <= rmin){
        //left > right
        if(source[i][0] > source[j][0]){
            source[i].swap(source[j]);
            //exchange result
            int temp = result[j];
            result[j] = result[i];
            result[i] = temp;

            i ++;
        }
        else if(source[i][0] < source[j][0])
            source[i].swap(source[j]);

            j ++;
        }

}

void merge_sort(vector< vector<double> >& source, vector< int >& result, int min, int max){
    if(max - min == 0){
            result[min] = min;
            return;
    }
    int median = (max - min) / 2;
    merge_sort(source, result, min , median);
    merge_sort(source, result, median + 1 , max);
    merge(source, result, min, median, median + 1, max);
}

int main(){

       vector < vector<double> >test (8, vector<double>(3));
       vector < int >result (8);
       vector < vector<double> >ttt;
    test[0][0]= 10;
    test[0][1]= 20;
    test[0][2]= 30;
    //(1,2,3)
    test[1][0]= 1;
    test[1][1]= 2;
    test[1][2]= 3;
    //(1000,2000,3000)
    test[2][0]= 1000;
    test[2][1]= 2000;
    test[2][2]= 3000;
    //(100,200,300)
    test[3][0]= 100;
    test[3][1]= 200;
    test[3][2]= 300;
    //(100,200,300)
    test[4][0]= 100;
    test[4][1]= 200;
    test[4][2]= 302;
    //(100,200,300)
    test[5][0]= 100;
    test[5][1]= 200;
    test[5][2]= 3030;
    //(100,200,300)
    test[6][0]= 1000000;
    test[6][1]= 2000000;
    test[6][2]= 3000000;
    test[7][0]= 10;
    test[7][1]= 20;
    test[7][2]= 30.5;
    merge_sort(test, result, 0 , 7);

    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < test[i].size(); j ++){
            cout << test[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i ++)cout << result[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? Where does it crash? Also, try to make a smaller test which crashes and then investigate it.

Comment: sorry, I have never used it, I will learn it  later.

Comment: Do you need to write your own merge sort? I was thinking you could have std::vector<int> of indices and sort that vector instead using std::sort with an appropriate function object.

Comment: Could you give me the example, I rarely use STL and have little know about it. Thank you.

Comment: @liang-yupan Check [this](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html) for a gdb tutorial (incase ur on a unix/linux machine. dnt knw abt windows)

Comment: std::sort here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely learn how to use debugging tools. Go step by step and see where unexpected things occur. If you don't know how to use one yet, try inserting `cout`s here and there. Observe the values of the variables by printing them to screen. I believe in this case you will be *debugging manually*
* :) By printing values you can see how your algorithm works step by step. It's good practice.

```
int median = (max - min) / 2;
```

I believe you should find median like `unsigned int median = (int)floor((max+min)/2);`

say `max = 3` and `min = 2`. According to your code median will be `0` which is irrelevant. At that point, when you call mergesort with this parameters, (min=2, max=median=0) the next median will be calculated as a negative index. Therefore using `unsigned int` as the median value will help you detect the problem. See, choosing types carefully actually helps you, this case is a very good example of it.

By fixing this mistake of yours, your program will terminate.

Comment: Thx for your advice, I will start to learn it and try to fix it.

Comment: Could you give me some hint why my algorithm didn't sort it normally?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters:

```
int median = (max - min) / 2;
```

should be

```
int median = (max + min) / 2;
```

You may want to start with [implementing merge sort in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030683/implementing-merge-sort-in-c)

and get yourself a good debugger. Also, you'll probably get useful more responses in the future if you post the actual error message you are getting.