# Counting Inversions in an array via merge sort

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

**Inversion Count** for an array indicates – how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If array is already sorted then inversion count is 0. If array is sorted in reverse order that inversion count is the maximum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int merge(int arr[],int temp[], int left, int mid, int right)
{
    int inv_count = 0;
    int i = left;
    int j = mid;
    int k = right;
    while((i <= mid-1) && (j <= right))
    {
        if(arr[i] <= arr[j])
        {
            temp[k++] = arr[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            temp[k++] = arr[j++];
            inv_count += (mid - i);
        }
    }
    while(i <= mid-1)
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    while(j <= right)
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];
    for(i = left; i <= right; i++)
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    return inv_count;
}

int _merge_sort(int arr[], int temp[], int left, int right)
{
    int mid, inv_count = 0;
    if(right > left)
    {
        mid = (right+left)/2;
        inv_count = _merge_sort(arr,temp,left,mid);
        inv_count += _merge_sort(arr,temp,mid+1,right);
        inv_count += merge(arr,temp,left,mid+1,right);
    }
    return inv_count;
 }

int merge_sort(int arr[], int array_size)
{
    int *temp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*array_size);
    return (_merge_sort(arr,temp,0,array_size-1));
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]= {1, 25, 12, 56, 36, 3, 0, 10, 8, 7};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<merge_sort(arr,10)<<"\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output for given array is 27 but i am getting 6. Plus my original array data got modified ( It's not sorted values has been changed).

Comment: Try stepping through a debugger to actually see what's happening when you run your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace int k = right by int k = left in function merge. I think expected output for this array is 27. Various implementations of merge sort had been discussed here [implementing merge sort in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030683/implementing-merge-sort-in-c)

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes the expected result for given array is 27.