# merge sort algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to write a C++ program that sorts a user input array using the merge algorithm.

Here's the split function:

```
void split(int numbers[], int size) {
    if (size == 1)
        return;

    int mid = size / 2;
    int firstPartSize = mid;
    int secondPartSize = size - mid;

    int *firstArray;
    firstArray = new int[firstPartSize];

    int *secondArray;
    secondArray = new int[secondPartSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i < mid)
            firstArray[i] = numbers[i];
        else
            secondArray[i - mid] = numbers[i];
    }

    split(firstArray, firstPartSize);
    split(secondArray, secondPartSize);
    merge(numbers, firstArray, firstPartSize, secondArray, secondPartSize);
}
```

Here's the merging function:

```
void merge(int outputArray[], int firstArray[], int n1, int secondArray[], int n2) {
    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (firstArray[i] < secondArray[j])
            outputArray[k++] = firstArray[i++];
        else
            outputArray[k++] = secondArray[j++];
    }

    while (i < n1)
        outputArray[k++] = firstArray[i++];
    while (j < n2)
        outputArray[k++] = secondArray[j++];

    for (int c = 0; c < n1+n2; c++)
    {
        cout << outputArray[c] << " ";
    }
}
```

When I try to insert an array, here's what I get

```
Enter the size of the array you want to sort:
3
Enter the elements of the array:
4
7
1
1 7 1 4 7 Press any key to continue
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I updated it, but i still get random numbers then sorted numbers at the end.

Comment: @MarcoAtef What did you update? `sizeof(outputArray)` yields you the size of a pointer variable (probably 8 bytes).

Comment: @MarcoAtef Did you read the link that I gave you, about what `sizeof` actually does? It **does not** give you the size of the array. In addition to that, did you try using the debugger, as suggested?

Comment: Yeah i changed it to c < n1+n2 which are the sizes of both arrays.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The debugger crashes, i don't really know why.

Comment: @MarcoAtef Once again, where? I can't see your update on the question.

Comment: @MarcoAtef I refuse to believe that the debugger itself crashes. Maybe the memory is lied out in different way, when debugger is attached, which, couple with (probable) UB present in your code, may force **your** program to crash, not debugger.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry, done.

Comment: I also updated the output that i get, it's sorted at the end of it but i don't know why it prints 1 , 7 for example.

Comment: @MarcoAtef Once again - use debugger (and fix, very obvious, memory leaks present in your code).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030683/implementing-merge-sort-in-c

Comment: not really related to your problem, but I feel like it could help. This looks like plain C with couts instead of printf. you might want to use `std::vector` and be safe about some problem you are having there. or just spend some more time messing around with arrays and memory! good luck

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct overall with a simple error. You are printing the output in one of the recursive steps and hence are getting the intermediate results mixed with the answer.

Removing the `cout` in the `merge` function and moving it out to a `main` function will do the trick:

```
void merge(int outputArray[], int firstArray[], int n1, int secondArray[], int n2) {
    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (firstArray[i] < secondArray[j])
            outputArray[k++] = firstArray[i++];
        else
            outputArray[k++] = secondArray[j++];
    }   

    while (i < n1) 
        outputArray[k++] = firstArray[i++];
    while (j < n2) 
        outputArray[k++] = secondArray[j++];

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int a[] = {1, 4, 7}; 
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    split(a, n); 

    cout << "The array is:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }   
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The array is:
1 4 7
```